# phpmyadmin Want kill a process but its busy

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a large MySQL database running on a that a group of users access through phpmMyAdmin.

At times they start a process that runs too long and they need to kill the process.
In theory this can be done from the home page under the processes tab where a users processes are show with a kill link.

This would be perfect except that the original process has mysql tied up. Getting a second phpmyadmin page to go to the processes kill page hangs waiting to make a connection.

Is there a way to overcome this. One way might be to prioritise certain processes in mysql.
Another way might be to write a cgi script that could kill mysql processes perhaps through a separate web server (two lines in Python) and given a higher "nice" priotory value.

I would rather be able to do it all through phpmyadmin configuration.

Comment: Try opening phpmyadmin in a different browser.

Answer (score 3):

Several options:

1. Use a different browser
2. Use Chrome's incognito mode
3. Close and reopen your browser
4. Clear your cookies